# Take bug report for specific application

Tags: debug, developer-options

I am starting Android development, and I am looking for a way to get a bug report from a user's phone.

I know about the `Settings / Developer options / Take bug report` system, but from what I have seen, it dumps *all* logs from all sorts of apps I don't really care about.

Is there a similar method which would generate a similar file, with just logs relevant to my app?

(I also know about `adb logcat`, which I can then filter on my computer during development, but it's not easy asking users to do that!)

Comment: You just program your app to generate log with a specific tag, and use `adb logcat` with filter to only show logs with that tag.

Comment: Although this question is asked from a developer POV, I'm voting to leave it open because it could also be thought of as how can a user collect enough information to report a bug to an app developer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try third party libraries such as [Android Bug Tracker](https://github.com/IvannKurchenko/Android-Log-Tracker/blob/master/README.md).  You can find many other on github.